# Get a 500 error from google when Migrating to OAuth 2.0 login (OpenID Connect) from OpenID 2.0

Tags: google-plus, google-openid, google-signin, google-oauth

When migrating to OAuth 2.0 login (OpenID Connect) from OpenID 2.0 I got an error from Google. `(500 error message)`. That only occurs when I use a personal account but  when I use my enterprise account, I can login successfully. I don't know what happened and what can I do to resolve this issue. Please help me to fix it.

Below is my login step by step:

1. start from my homepage → Select Google Login
2. Google Login → Select a Google Account Ref Url：http://goo.gl/gkOamz
3. Select Google Account → `personal@gmail.com` It is a personal account, not an enterprise account. (`personal@enterprise.com`)
4. Permissions page → Select Agree Requires that you grant the following permissions
5. Select Agree Permissions → Get an error message page from Google.

   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=2c46c2a1847a7f4&hl=zh_TW&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAVO7m-Pml8ERHZRM12ZiAtXqD04AbUFRi
6. Error Page → Error Message

> 500. That’s an error.
>
> There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.

Comment: Make sure you properly URL-encoded values for all parameters including `redirect_uri`, `hd` and `openid.realm`. They should have become doubly url-encoded in the URL that you gave (just like `state` is), but they aren't.

Comment: I URL-encoded all param, but still occur the same error 500.
Consider for that my organization acount can login successful.
If the reason is url encode problem,then organization acount will error too,right?

Comment: Your URL looks OK now, that's n

Comment: But I still got an error 500 when I use a personal account.

Comment: Hello, my name is Miguel and I work in the Google Identity team. I will need more information to properly debug this issue, contact me via gueles at google dot com and we can take it from there...

Comment: I found the problem is about oauth 2.0 login param "hd".I remove "hd" param then it works fine now, thanks.
Use the hd parameter to limit sign-in to a particular Google Apps hosted domain. (Read more at hd.)

Comment: @MiguelAndres I get consistently 500 with this request (hybrid flow, ID Token only): https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=id_token&scope=email&client_id=905871143468-jsau5ivjak4gui6mop1l1ec5suk8ecnu.apps.googleusercontent.com&edirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fcb%3Fprovider%3Dgoogle&state=123&display=page&nonce=1233

Comment: Marco, it seems to be a problem with your client credentials, make sure to use a valid client id and registered redirect url.